# Is it safe to delete a pointer that was cast from void in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

Say I've got something like that in a public header:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();

protected:
    virtual ~MyClass();

private:
    void *pSomeInternalClass;
}
```

And here's my implementation:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    pSomeInteralClass = (void *) new SomeInternalClass();
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    SomeInternalClass *pTemp = (SomeInternalClass *) pSomeInternalClass;
    delete pTemp;
    pSomeInternalClass = NULL;
}
```

The idea behind the void pointer is that I dont't have to include the definitions for the internal class in the public headers.

My question is: am I handling the void pointer in a safe way? Is there any problem with its deletion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's safe as long as you cast it back to it's original type.

But you don't need to do that. Just forward-declare your internal type in your public header, and you don't need to do this nasty cast.

```
class YourClass {
  ...
  private:
    class Internal;
    Internal *pInternal;
};
```

Comment: Afaik, casting back to the original type is not necessary. Only the address is used to find the corresponding block in memory.

Comment: Much better idea to declare the class inside the private: section of MyClass, rather than exposing it at the same level as MyClass to the header's clients.

Comment: No, you need to cast to the original type (virtual destructor relaxes this a bit). `A *a = new A(); B *b = (B*)(void*)a; delete b;` will call `B::~B`, not `A::~A`, @user198397

Comment: @user198397: it is necessary, other types may have different point representations, or apply different tweaks when dereferencing the pointer... e.g. to find virtual bases, functions etc..  All the usual support for such tweaks isn't available after casting to `void*`.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to include the definitions for the class in the public headers. i.e.

```
class SomeInternalClass ;
class MyClass 
{ 
public: 
    MyClass(); 

protected: 
    virtual ~MyClass(); 

private: 
    SomeInternalClass *pSomeInternalClass; 
}
```

Comment: Much better idea to declare the class inside the `private:` section of `MyClass`, rather than exposing it at the same level as MyClass to the header's clients.